# sending only certain input from FormGroup in angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I want to send only certain input from my FormGroup . Here is my code

```
createForm() {
    this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
      'firstName': [null, Validators.required],
      'lastName': [null, Validators.required],
      'zipCode': [null, Validators.required],
      'CompanyName': [null, Validators.required],
      'Phone': [null, Validators.required],
      'companyId': [null, Validators.required],`enter code here`
      'checkbox1': [true],
      'checkbox2': [false]
    });

  }
```

It has two checkboxes. The input is taken according to whether the checkbox is clicked or not. So if I uncheck **checkbox2** then I don't need to send **CompanyName, Phone,companyId** etc. How can I  do this in angular?

Comment: if you "disable" a FormControl, form.value not include this element. BTW in any case you can create a temporally object before to send, e.g: `const data={firstName:this.myForm.firstName}` only contain the property 'firstName'

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the form values on submit and need to create custom post object.

```
save(event: Event) {
  Object.keys(this.myForm.controls).forEach(field => {
      const control = this.myForm.get(field);
      control.markAsTouched({ onlySelf: true });
  });
  if (this.myForm.valid) {
     try {
         const formValues = this.myForm.value;
         console.log(formValues);
         //You can check the condition here and pass the values as you need eg:
         cost postParams = {
            field1:value1,
            field2:value2,
         }
     }catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
     }
  }
}
```